# Control character in awk output

Tags: awk, special-characters

I have the following `bash`/`awk` script, which does what I want, except that it adds a control symbol that I do not know what it means.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Merge two cross section files from Resummino

file1=filein1
file2=filein2
fileout=fileout

awk '{
        xs_nlo[$1," ",$2] += $4
        xs_lo[$1," ",$2] += $3
    }
    END {
        for (xs in xs_nlo){
            print(xs, xs_lo[xs], xs_nlo[xs])
        }
    }
' "${file1}" "${file2}"
```

Possible content of `filein1`:

```
100.000 500.000 7.878892e+00 1.027803e+01
100.000 1000.000 9.667085e+00 1.274467e+01
100.000 2000.000 1.029358e+01 1.361803e+01
100.000 5000.000 1.049836e+01 1.390297e+01
100.000 10000.000 1.052944e+01 1.394593e+01
```

and similar for `filein2`, except that the last two values in each line differ. The `awk` script is supposed to add up the third values in each line, assuming the first and the second values are the same. Same for the fourth value.

The output file is supposed to have the same structure as the input files. In the console, the output file looks the same, but opening it in `vim`, I see a control character that is not easy to search for:

```
100.000^\ ^\300.000 3.42 4.57283
```

What does this `^\ ^\` mean and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: the source of the problem is your separator `$1," ",$2`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yeah, well, I thought so. So I replaced the `" "` with `"x"` and then replaced `x` with `" "` in the end again, but I get the same output. How do I fix it?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Okay, I understand now. I was focusing on `" "`, thinking that the whitespace is the problem, but the only problem was the `,`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest If you write an answer, no matter how short, I will mark it as solution.

Comment: ok, added the answer

Comment: if you want your indexes to be : $1 concatened with space and $2:  change `[$1," ",$2]` into `[$1 " " $2]`  (ie, drop the commas, which are used in a different context, for example as separator to a printf arguments)

Comment: note also that your 'for ... in ...' will not keep the order. If you also want to keep the order, you need to have a separate array (ex: indx[n++]) keeping track of the order of apparition of each indexes, and you use that one to retrieve the indexes in the right order. Avoid using "index" as its name, as it is one of awk reserved keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the problem is in separator `$1," ",$2`.

From documentation:

> Multidimensional arrays are supported in awk through concatenation of
>   indices into one string. awk converts the indices into strings (see
>   Conversion) and concatenates them together, with a separator between
>   them. This creates a single string that describes the values of the
>   separate indices. The combined string is used as a single index into
>   an ordinary, one-dimensional array. The separator used is the value of
>   the built-in variable ***SUBSEP***

---

> ***SUBSEP*** 
> The subscript separator. It has the default value of "**\034**" and is used to separate the parts of the indices of a
>   multidimensional array. Thus, the expression ‘foo["A", "B"]’ really
>   accesses foo["A\034B"]

---

*Standard awk simulates multidimensional arrays by separating subscript values with commas. The values are concatenated into a single string, separated by the value of SUBSEP.
The fact that such a subscript was created in this way is not retained; thus, changing **SUBSEP** may have unexpected consequences.*

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of:

> What does this ^\ ^\ mean and how can I get rid of it?

Some other answer has already explained that the comma (`,`) in `[$1," ",$2]` becomes the SUBSEP. Thta is the character `\034` (in octal) or `0x1C` (in hex).

That character could also be written in control encoding as `^\`.
That is the reason to have the two `^\` in the output.

The solution is to take back (from the awk program) the control of how the indices of the array are created. The most simple solution is to concatenate the two fields (`$1` and `$2`) together, however, that will make equal this two array keys (in no particular language):

```
$1=abc  $2=def     $1$2 is abcdef
$1=a    $2=bcdef   $1$2 is abcdef
```

The solution is to use a character that does not appear in the values of $1 or $2. Space may seem like a candidate, but the FS (field separator) is a more general solution which also could separate the fields when printed. Thus, this script works for any FS:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Merge two cross section files from Resummino

file1=filein1
file2=filein2
fileout=fileout


awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {
          point = $1 FS $2
          xs_nlo[ point ] += $4
          xs_lo [ point ] += $3
     }
     END {
         for (xs in xs_nlo){
             print(xs, xs_lo[xs], xs_nlo[xs])
         }
     }
    ' "${file1}" "${file2}"
```

Comment: Thanks, very informative. Too late to mark it as accepted answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `xs_nlo[$1," ",$2]` with `xs_nlo[$1" "$2]` fixed it.